# How do I output power to GPIO pin?

Tags: gpio, python, uart

I have GPIO to USB adaptor. There is a small light connected to the USB end. I have 4 TTL cables Red, Black, Green and White. By black cable is in pin 6 (ground), white in pin 8 and green in pin 10. I wrote a script to control the GPIO14 and GPIO15, but the light is not switching on. It does switch on when I connect red wire to 3v3 power or 5v power but I read that individual GPIO ports do provide 3v3 power, but how do I make it work? Maybe I need a transistor to turn on and off an USB if it is a serial cable? or some other equipment?

```
import RPi.GPIO as io
import time

io.setmode(io.BCM)
io.setwarnings(False)

ioG = [14, 15] #14 - white / 15 - Green

io.setup(ioG, io.OUT)
io.output(ioG, True)
print "LED on"

time.sleep(5)

io.output(ioG, False)
print "LED off"

io.cleanup()
```

Comment: Could you include a link to the GPIO to USB adapter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to power USB through GPIO python](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/62914/how-to-power-usb-through-gpio-python)

Comment: @joan Here is the link: https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/usb-to-uart-serial-console-cable?utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=googlepla&variant=288389664&gclid=CjwKEAiA0fnFBRC6g8rgmICvrw0SJADx1_zA6qSgWsO-qHQxKrz8va22Y7wuqhI5Q5ZIyMuVzo79sRoCm9fw_wcB

Comment: @joan yes sorry about previous question, I did changed pins and not using red cable. The code is slightly improved as well.